# Como podria leer un valor en pandas y copiarlo en otro valor automaticamente

Tags: python, pandas

Como podria leer un valor en pandas y copiarlo en otro valor automaticamente.

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente grafo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos dos grafos son simetricos; Es decir la misma distancia que existe de "A" a "B" es la misma distancia que existe de "D" a "E". . Igualmente la misma distancia que existe de "A" a "C" es la misma distancia que existe de "D" a "F"

Ahora bien. Supongamos que yo quiero esos datos en una hoja de excel, la primera opcion que tengo es hacerlo a mano:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso es sencillo porque son unos pocos valores, pero si es una matriz muy grande es dificil,monotono y me tenderia a equivocar.

Entonces lo que quiero es llenar(en este ejemplo) el valor de "A" a "B" en excel y que se llenen los otros valores en un DataFrame de pandas.

Es decir, supongamos que tenemos los siguientes datos de excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora ya que las distancias son las mismas quiero que se llenen automáticamente (Como la hoja de excel que llené mas arriba a mano). Por lo tanto realizo el siguiente codigo :

```
 import pandas as pd

data_raw = pd.read_excel("datos_grafos.xls").\
set_index('indice') #imprime el excel en forma de matriz
                                     #con las letras como indice

data_raw.at['D','E']= data_raw.at['A','B']
''' como la distancia A B es la misma que D E copio el
valor de A B y lo pego en D E'''

data_raw.at['D','F']= data_raw.at['A','C']
''' como la distancia A C es la misma que D F copio el
valor de A C y lo pego en D F'''
```

Pero obviamente eso no tiene sentido porque es muchisimo mas laborioso que poner el valor directamente en excel. .

Y básicamente queria alguna sugerencia que algoritmo podria usar o si me podrian dar una mano de como comenzar para que se copien los valores que se repitan automáticamente y no hacerlos a mano en excel.

Disculpen lo largo de la pregunta

Comment: No queda claro cuántas celdas tienes que copiar de este modo. En el ejemplo son solo tres, pero imagino que en la práctica serán muchas más. ¿Cómo tendrías en ese caso espeficicadas qué parejas de celdas han de ser iguales?

Comment: @abulafia. Claro, en realidad tengo que copiar una matriz de 22 x 22 . Pero eso no importa. Al hacerla con solo 3 la puedo extrapolar al tamaño que quiera.

Comment: @abulafia: ''Cómo tendrías en ese caso espeficicadas qué parejas de celdas han de ser iguales? ". . Precisamente ese es otro problema con el cual necesito tratar. Por eso a pesar de lo sencillo del planteamiento de este problema, se me hace muy dificil , incluso tratar de modelarlo para resolverlo

Comment: Pues antes de modelarlo... ¿cómo tienes ahora mismo esa información? Se trata solo de los dibujos de los grafos? ¿Hay una lista de etiquetas "equivalentes"? (por ejemplo A-D, B-E, C-F) o cómo?

Comment: @abualifa si, se trata solo de los dibujos de los grafos. Para hacerlo mas facil, imagina que estoy haciendo un travel salesman problem , y cada círculo es una ciudad y cada linea la distancia entre las cuidades

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a ver si lo entendí. Para empezar voy a crear un dataframe como el que creo que creas tú desde excel, pero en mi caso lo crearé desde texto para que el ejemplo sea reproducible:

```
data = """indice;A;B;C;D;E;F
A;;4;7;
B;
C;
D;
E;
F;
"""

import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=";").set_index("indice").fillna("-")
```

El dataframe que obtengo es el siguiente (he rellenado con guiones los lugares donde no hay números, para que se vean mejor, pero podría haberlo rellenado con cadenas vacías):

```
        A  B  C  D  E  F
indice                  
A       -  4  7  -  -  -
B       -  -  -  -  -  -
C       -  -  -  -  -  -
D       -  -  -  -  -  -
E       -  -  -  -  -  -
F       -  -  -  -  -  -
```

A partir de estos datos de entrada lo que creo que quieres hacer es:

- Rellenar automáticamente las celdas "simétricas" de las dadas. Es decir, ya que hay un 4 en las coordenadas (A,B) quieres un 4 también en las coordenadas (B,A)
- Rellenar además las celdas que correspondan para obtener una "copia" de ese mismo grafo, sólo que con los nodos D,E,F en el papel de A,B,C

Para lo segundo es necesario crear una estructura de datos que relacione los nombres de los nodos del grafo "original" con los nombres de los nodos en el grafo "equivalente". Un diccionario como el siguiente podría servir bien para esto:

```
equivalencias = {"A": "D", 
                 "B": "E", 
                 "C": "F"}
```

Pues dada esta información, el siguiente bucle hace, creo, lo que buscas:

```
nodos = "ABC"   # Nombres de los nodos del grafo original

for fila in nodos:
  for columna in nodos:
    valor = df.loc[fila, columna]
    if valor != "-":
      df.loc[columna, fila] = valor     # Si tenemos rellenado AB, rellenamos BA
      # Y rellenamos también sus "gemelos"
      fila2 = equivalencias.get(fila)
      columna2 = equivalencias.get(columna)
      if fila2 and columna2:
        df.loc[fila2, columna2] = valor
        df.loc[columna2, fila2] = valor
```

El dataframe resultante de la ejecución de ese bucle es:

```
        A  B  C  D  E  F
indice                  
A       -  4  7  -  -  -
B       4  -  -  -  -  -
C       7  -  -  -  -  -
D       -  -  -  -  4  7
E       -  -  -  4  -  -
F       -  -  -  7  -  -
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Nunca se me hubiera ocurrido algo asi. Ahora voy a estudiarlo y extrapolarlo a una matriz mas grande . Ademas de que,por ejemplo los nodos "A" y "D" tambien van conectados esto me va a servir mucho para comenzar. .

Comment: una pregunta un poco personal, te parecio muy dificil ayudarme a resolver el problema o te pareció un poco complicado ?

Comment: La idea de cómo atacar el problema se me ocurrió enseguida (el diccionario de equivalencias y que habría que hacer un bucle para ir copiando las celdas pertinentes). El código del bucle en sí me costó unos cuantos intentos hasta lograr que funcionara como quería, y evitar repeticiones inútiles. Digamos que encontré "dificultad media". Ah, por cierto, si la respuesta resuelve la pregunta puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Claro. Muchas gracias. Espero que de vez en cuando, cuando realize alguna pregunta la puedas ver y si es posible ayudar. Saludos.